# Using wget along with awk to download files

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I have a csv called `test.csv` that contains urls to be dowloaded in its first column. I want to download the urls using `wget`. How can I do this in shell?

I have used the command below but no success:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1}' test.csv | wget -P download_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pipe the filenames into wget, but you can run the command for each item with the filename appended to the end

try this and review the list of commands it will run

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1}' test.csv | xargs -n1 echo wget -P download_dir
```

then remove `echo` and run it again, and it'll execute the commands instead of printing them